# Не могу разобраться с timeout

Tags: python, timeout

Не могу понять как использовать timeout.
Нужно что то наподобие такого

```
client, addr = sock.accept()
#Если есть подключение
#Что - то делает
#Если 2 секунды нет подключения
data = client.recv(1024)
```

И так же для `recv()`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте socket.settimeout -https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout